# Any local algebraic group is birationally equivalent to an algebraic group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In [this](http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~nagyg/pub/grishkov_nagy3.pdf) paper, page $6$ the authors  state the following:

> By Weil’s theorem $[17]$, any local algebraic group is birationally
>   equivalent to an algebraic group.

Where

$[17]$ A.Weil. On algebraic groups of transformations. Amer. J. Math. 77, (1955), 355-391.

I would like to know if I can find that Theorem in some book about Algebraic Groups.

I would appreciate your help.

N.B.: I asked this also on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92193/any-local-algebraic-group-is-birationally-equivalent-to-an-algebraic-group).